# How can I find out when on android 2.3+ a phone call starts and stops?

Tags: android, phone-call

I need my app to find out when a phone call is taking place.

It should work on when another phone is being called and also when a call is answered. I just need my app to get notified of exactly when the connection starts and when it stops (not the dialing, ringing, etc.).

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use broadcast class to achieve this as below:

```
public class PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(new CustomPhoneStateListener(context),
            PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}

class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    // private static final String TAG = "PhoneStateChanged";
    Context context; // Context to make Toast if required

    public CustomPhoneStateListener(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        switch (state) {

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            //WHEN PHONE WILL BE IDLE       
        break;

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            // when Off hook i.e in call
        break;

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            // when Ringing
        break;

        default:
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry for the late reply but this is exactly what I was looking for.